# Как подсчитать количество одинаковых значений элементов в словарях по заданному ключу?

Tags: python

Как оптимально подсчитать одинаковые словари по ключу?

Например, есть словари:

```
S1={ 'имя':'женя', 'дом':'77'}
S2={ 'имя':'егор', 'дом':'77'}
S3={ 'имя':'иван', 'дом':'55'} 
S4={ 'имя':'вася', 'дом':'44'}
S5={ 'имя':'жора', 'дом':'33'}
```

Вывод:

> в доме 77 живет 2, в доме 55 - 1 , в доме 44 - 1, в доме 33 - 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оптимально можно считать по разному. Можно оптимально по скорости, по памяти, по сложности понимания написанного, по количеству используемых библиотек.

вот один из вариантов, на мой взгляд несложно понять что происходит, и оптимально по памяти так-как не происходит копирования исходных данных

```
from itertools import groupby

a=[{ 'имя':'женя', 'дом':'77'},
   { 'имя':'егор', 'дом':'77'},
   { 'имя':'иван', 'дом':'55'},
   { 'имя':'вася', 'дом':'44'},
   { 'имя':'жора', 'дом':'33'}]

r = groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda x: x['дом']), lambda x: x['дом'])

for k, g in r:
     print(k, len(list(g)))
```

Comment: Думаю, важно отметить, что ваше решение будет работать только на отсортированном по номеру дома списке.

Comment: да, вы правы. спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 5):

Я бы воспользовался [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [10]: from collections import Counter

In [11]: Counter([d['дом'] for d in [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5]])
Out[11]: Counter({'33': 1, '44': 1, '55': 1, '77': 2})
```

или, [как посоветовал @TimofeyBondarev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578332/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5/578364#comment766751_578364), более экономный вариант:

```
In [4]: Counter(d['дом'] for d in [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5])
Out[4]: Counter({'33': 1, '44': 1, '55': 1, '77': 2})
```

Comment: Если воспользоваться генераторным выражением, можно не создавать дополнительного промежуточного списка и упростить запись: `Counter(d['дом'] for d in [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5])`

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, спасибо! Добавил в ответ...

Comment: Можно упомянуть `Counter(map(itemgetter('дом'), dicts))`, но это менее читаемая альтернатива (вариант в ответе лучше).

Answer (score 1):

```
sg = tuple(s.get('дом') for s in [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5])
x = {s: sg.count(s) for s in set(sg)}
print(x)
```

out:

```
{'55': 1, '44': 1, '33': 1, '77': 2}
```

быстродействие

```
import timeit, random
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

def T_tuple():
    sg = tuple(s.get('дом') for s in S)
    return {s: sg.count(s) for s in set(sg)}

def C_Counter():
    return Counter([d['дом'] for d in S])

def G_groupby():
    r = groupby(sorted(S, key=lambda x: x['дом']), lambda x: x['дом'])
    return [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in r]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fns = C_Counter, G_groupby, T_tuple

    for s, h in [(10000, 10), (10000, 100), (10000, 1000), (10, 10), (10, 100), (10, 1000)]:
        S = [{'имя': r, 'дом': random.randrange(h)} for r in range(s)]
        print('\nlen(S):', s, 'len(дом):', h)
        t = [(fn.__name__,
              timeit.Timer(fn).timeit(10)) for fn in fns]

        for e, (n, tmt) in enumerate(sorted(t, key=lambda r: r[1]), start=1):
            print("{}' {:.4} {}".format(e, tmt, n))
```

out:

```
len(S): 10000 len(дом): 10
1' 0.01853 C_Counter
2' 0.05015 T_tuple
3' 0.06918 G_groupby

len(S): 10000 len(дом): 100
1' 0.01672 C_Counter
2' 0.08368 G_groupby
3' 0.2862 T_tuple

len(S): 10000 len(дом): 1000
1' 0.02135 C_Counter
2' 0.09862 G_groupby
3' 2.634 T_tuple

len(S): 10 len(дом): 10
1' 7.795e-05 T_tuple
2' 0.0001365 G_groupby
3' 0.000157 C_Counter

len(S): 10 len(дом): 100
1' 0.0001153 C_Counter
2' 0.0001153 T_tuple
3' 0.000209 G_groupby

len(S): 10 len(дом): 1000
1' 0.0001025 T_tuple
2' 0.0001058 C_Counter
3' 0.0001683 G_groupby
```

Comment: Это решение не очень оптимально: вы создаёте временный кортеж с номерами домов, временное множество с номерами домов  и используете квадратичный алгоритм подсчёта.

Answer (score 0):

```
houses = {}
for i in [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5]:
    houses[i['дом']] = houses.setdefault(i['дом'], 0) + 1

print(houses)
```

out:
{'77': 2, '55': 1, '44': 1, '33': 1}

Comment: Конечно хорошо что вы опубликовали решение, но к нему также стоит добавить описание, чтобы любой пользователь смог разобраться в вашем коде.

Comment: это просто вариант решения задачи, не знаю какое здесь можно добавить описание